# Apply border-radius to box-shadow but not to the div itself

Tags: html, css, border

I want to apply a border radius to a `box-shadow` but not the div itself, so the end result will be a rounded box shadow on the left side with 90 degree angle div.

```css
.div-to-style {
    -webkit-box-shadow: -20px 0px 0px 0px blue;
    -moz-box-shadow: -20px 0px 0px 0px blue;
    box-shadow: -20px 0px 0px 0px blue;
    border-radius: 8px 8px 8px 8px;

    background-color: red;
    width: 200px;
    height: 50px;
    margin-left:40px;
}
```

```html
<div class="div-to-style">
</div>

<p>
Want the red section to have a straight border on the left
</p>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/alair016/vdcohttk/

The problem with this CSS is that the `border-radius` is applied to the `box-shadow` as well as the div on the left side.

Comment: You can't do it that way, the box-shadow is property of an element, not an element, as Paulie_D said above. You can't set a property on a property. You can make a transparent div (b) below the other element (a) and give that element the same size properties as (a) but give it a border-radius and a box-shadow. It will then appear as if you have a square box (a) with a rounded shadow (from box (b))

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The box shadow is not an element. You can't add border-radius to an **effect**.

Try a pseudo-element instead:

```css
.div-to-style {
  border-radius: 0 8px 8px 0;
  background-color: red;
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  margin-left: 40px;
  position: relative;
}
.div-to-style::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: -20px;
  width: 20px;
  height: 100%;
  background: blue;
  z-index: -1;
  border-radius: 8px 0 0 8px;
}
```

```html
<div class="div-to-style">
</div>
```

**Bonus Option:** No pseudo-element - Gradient background

```css
.div-to-style {
  border-radius: 8px;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, blue, blue 20px, red 20px);
  width: 200px;
  padding-left: 20px;
  height: 50px;
  margin-left: 40px;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="div-to-style">
</div>
```

Comment: just implemented the Bonus Option with no pseudo-element.  Exactly what I needed.  Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can use a pseudo-element to create the shadow, and apply the `border-radius` to that pseudo-element.

### Working Example:

```css
.div-to-style {
    background-color: red;
    width: 200px;
    height: 50px;
    margin-left:40px;
}
.div-to-style:before {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
    z-index: -1;
    -webkit-box-shadow: -20px 0px 0px 0px blue;
    -moz-box-shadow: -20px 0px 0px 0px blue;
    box-shadow: -20px 0px 0px 0px blue;
    border-radius: 8px 8px 8px 8px;
}
```

```html
<div class="div-to-style">
</div>

<p>
Want the red section to have a straight border on the left
</p>
```

Answer (score -1):

The gist is, you need 2 divs. Add the box shadow and radius to the outer div, and the other background or border styles to the inner div.

```
.div-to-style {
        -webkit-box-shadow: -20px 0px 0px 0px blue;
        -moz-box-shadow: -20px 0px 0px 0px blue;
        box-shadow: -20px 0px 0px 0px blue;
        border-radius: 8px 8px 8px 8px;
        margin-left: 40px;
    }

.inner-style {
  background-color: red;
        width: 200px;
        height: 50px;
}

<div class="div-to-style">
<div class="inner-style">
</div>
</div>

<p>
Want the red section to have a straight border on the left
</p>
```

Here is a code example:
https://jsfiddle.net/vdcohttk/2/

== Edit

If you're going to downvote, please write a comment explaining *why*. Thanks!